# How to use unwind segues when showing a View Controllers on top of a Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, unwind-segue

I'm having an issue with unwinding View Controllers on top of a Tab Bar Controller.

**Path:**

- A button from (1) segues to (2) with a show segue.
- A button from (2) segues to (3) with a custom segue - code added below.
- When clicking on a button from (3) is want to unwind segue to (1) with a normal animation.

**Issue:**

When clicking on the button on (3) to unwind. (3) closes without animation, (2) is shown, and closes with the regular animation, and then showing (1).

How do I prevent (2) from showing - and having the nice animation from (3) to (1)?

[image]

**Custom segue:**

```
class SegueFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        let src = self.source
        let dst = self.destination

        src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       options: .curveEaseInOut,
                       animations: {
                        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        },
                       completion: { finished in
                        src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Does (3) have to be able to go back to (2)?

Comment: @remingtonchan No, only back to (1).
I'm will try testing it out with a container view controller. It works when (2) and (3) are wrapped in a navigation controller.